# How do i get the last insert rowid

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have this code but cant access the last insert rowid. Instead i get a letter such as m or s as the id. what could be wrong?

```
conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE input1 (id integer primary key autoincrement ,
                                    name)''')

conn.execute("INSERT INTO INPUT1 (NAME) VALUES (?);", (name3,))
conn.commit()

rows =[]
for row in conn.execute('SELECT * FROM INPUT1 WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM INPUT1);'):
id  = id[0]
rows.append((id))            
print(id)                
break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [cursor.lastrowid](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#optional-db-api-extensions)

Try this code

```
//
cursor=conn.cursor()

cursor.execute(INSERT INTO INPUT1 (NAME) VALUES (?);", (name3,))
print(cursor.lastrowid)
```