# How do I make a return statement from this loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I have this code and i need to get the lastrowid as a return statement. How can i fix it

```
def main():   
   while True:      
      #code here
      for item in name2:#break              
         conn = sqlite3.connect("foods.db")
         cursor = conn.cursor()               
         cursor.execute("INSERT INTO INPUT33 (NAME) VALUES (?);", (name2,))      
         cursor.execute("select MAX(rowid) from [input33];")
         conn.commit() 
         conn.close()      
         for rowid in cursor:break         
         for elem in rowid:
             return rowid#this is not working

            print(m)
```

Comment: I'm confused - you've pretty much already asked how to retrieve the value in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216529/how-do-i-get-the-last-insert-rowid) which you've accepted an answer to. Why is that not applicable here?

Comment: @user3346746: **how** is it not working? You are not using `cursor.lastrowid` here.

Comment: And why not use `cursor.fetchone()[0]` here, instead of the strange loop with one break, then loop over the row with return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *closed the database*, so any cursor no longer has access to the data. Retrieve the data *before closing*. I am assuming here that you have a reason to re-open the database in a loop here.

```
def main():   
    while True:      
       for item in name2:
           conn = sqlite3.connect("foods.db")
           cursor = conn.cursor()
           with conn:             
               cursor.execute("INSERT INTO INPUT33 (NAME) VALUES (?);", (name2,))      
               cursor.execute("select MAX(rowid) from [input33];")
               rowid = cursor.fetchone()[0]
           conn.close()
           return rowid
```