# How do I get generated uuid of last insert in python?

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, mysql-connector-python

How do i get the generated uuid_short of my last insert in python?

`cursor.lastrowid` as recommended by [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216529/how-do-i-get-the-last-insert-rowid) always returns 0

Here is my code

```py
import mysql.connector as DB
addlink = "INSERT INTO links (i,action,client,file) values (uuid_short(),%s,%s,%s)"
cursor.execute(addlink,link)
print(cursor.lastrowid)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`cursor.lastrowid`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-lastrowid.html) returns the value generated for an **`AUTO_INCREMENT` column** by the previous `INSERT` statement. It can't be used if you generate an id by other means.

You could first make a query to generate a UUID, then do an `INSERT`, e.g.:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT UUID_SHORT()')
uuid, = cursor.fetchone()
cursor.execute(addlink, (uuid, *other_params))
```